# I have created a table with some records using with JavaScript only, I want to set my array with objects to local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```js
var items2 = [
  {name:'HP 1Laptop', id:'Item1251', price:1001}, 
  {name:'HP 2Laptop', id:'Item1252', price:1002}, 
  {name:'HP 3Laptop', id:'Item1253', price:1003}, 
  {name:'HP 4Laptop', id:'Item1254', price:1004}, 
  {name:'HP 5Laptop', id:'Item1250', price:1005}, 
  {name:'HP 6Laptop', id:'Item1256', price:1006}, 
  {name:'HP 7Laptop', id:'Item1257', price:1007}, 
  {name:'HP 8Laptop', id:'Item1258', price:1008}, 
 ]; 
var items = [];
function saveData(){
 localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify(items2))
}
function loadData(){
var arr1 = localStorage.getItem('localData');
items = JSON.parse(arr1);
}
saveData();
loadData();
 
var globalIndex;
var updateBtn = document.getElementById('updateRow');
var addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
var numberFieldValue = document.getElementById('numberOfRecords');

var recordsCounting = document.getElementById('counter');
var updatedRow = document.getElementById('countries');
 
function recordsLoading(){
var data='';
if(items.length >= 0){
for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++){
data+= '<tr>';
data+= '<td>'+ items[i].name +'</td>';
data+= '<td>'+ items[i].id +'</td>';
data+= '<td>'+ items[i].price +'</td>';
data+= '<td><button class="btn btn-info" onclick="editingRecord('+i+')">Edit</button> <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delRecord('+i+')">Delete</button></td></tr>';
 
}
document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = data;
}
  recordsCounting.innerText =  items.length ;
}
 
recordsLoading();
/*From Here CRUD Operations are started*/

/*get the userdata from the current input fields*/
var itemName = document.getElementById('addNewitemName');
var itemId = document.getElementById('addNewitemID');
var itemprice = document.getElementById('addNewitemPrice');

/*This is for Adding records to the table*/
 function addingRecord(){
   if(itemName.value!=='' && itemId.value!=='' && itemprice.value !== ''){
    items.push({name:itemName.value, id:itemId.value,price:itemprice.value});
 items2.push({name:itemName.value, id:itemId.value,price:itemprice.value});
    recordsLoading();
    itemName.value = '';
    itemId.value = '';
    itemprice.value = '';
   }

 itemName.focus();
 }
 
 /*This is For Deleting a record from the table*/
function delRecord(indexValue){
items.splice(indexValue, 1);
 recordsLoading();
 }
/*This is for to edit existing record values*/ 
 function editingRecord(indexValue){
  itemName.value = items[indexValue].name;
  itemId.value = items[indexValue].id;
  itemprice.value = items[indexValue].price;
  updateBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
  addBtn.style.display = 'none'
  globalIndex = indexValue;
 }
 
 /*This is for update edited Value in the Table*/
 function update(){
items[globalIndex].name = itemName.value;
items[globalIndex].id = itemId.value;
items[globalIndex].price = itemprice.value;
itemName.value = "";
itemId.value = "";
itemprice.value= "";
recordsLoading();
 }
```

```html
<!-- I need to retrieve my data from local Storage, I know local
     storage concept but I don't know how it works with real time
     data -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Countries CRUD</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #updateRow{
      display: none;
    }
 .scrollView{
 max-height:350px;
 overflow-Y:auto;
 }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<hr/>
<form action="#"> 
<div class="form-group">
 
  
  
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <!-- <tr>  -->
  <!-- <td colspan="3"><input type="number" id="numberOfRecords" placeholder="Enter Number Of Items To Disaplay in Below Table" class="form-control"></td>  -->
  <!-- <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="renderRecords();">Create</button></td>  -->
   <!-- </tr> -->
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="addNewitemName" placeholder="Enter Item Name" class="form-control"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="addNewitemID" placeholder="Enter Item ID" class="form-control"></td>
  <td><input type="number" id="addNewitemPrice" placeholder="Enter Item Price" class="form-control"></td>
  <td width="150"><button onclick="addingRecord()" id="addBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add</button><button class="btn btn-info" id="updateRow" onclick="update()"> Update </button></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</form>

<div style="padding:5px 0px;">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
  Available Records : <span class="badge badge-light" id="counter"></span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="scrollView">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th onclick="sorting('name');">Name</th>
 <th onclick="sorting('id')">Item ID</th>
 <th onclick="sorting('price')" >Item Price</th>
 <th width="150"></th>
  </tr>
    <tbody id="countries">
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="saveData();">Save Data</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="loadData();">Retrive Data</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hear Records loading from browser localStorage but i am strucked at CRUD operations on It

Answer (score 3):

To save an array of objects into localStorage first stringify that array of objects, then save it into localStorage. When it is retrieved from localStorage parse it to get the initial array.
To save anything into the localStorage use `localStorage.setItem('name',value);`
By default the item saved in localStorage becomes *String* type.
To retrieve the saved item from localStorage, use `localStorage.getItem('name');`

```
 var items = [
  {name:'HP 1Laptop', id:'Item1251', price:1001}, 
  {name:'HP 2Laptop', id:'Item1252', price:1002}, 
  {name:'HP 3Laptop', id:'Item1253', price:1003}, 
  {name:'HP 4Laptop', id:'Item1254', price:1004}, 
  {name:'HP 5Laptop', id:'Item1250', price:1005}, 
  {name:'HP 6Laptop', id:'Item1256', price:1006}, 
  {name:'HP 7Laptop', id:'Item1257', price:1007}, 
  {name:'HP 8Laptop', id:'Item1258', price:1008}, 
 ]; 

 localStorage.setItem('array' , JSON.stringify(items));
 console.log("saved array is\n", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('array')));
```

Comment: yah i know this one but how can i retain my data if i edited or added a new record in my table

Comment: How can i push a new object to that array which is already exist in our Local Storage

Comment: You need to use `localStorage.setItem()` again to modify the array content. First, retrieve the array using _getItem()_ then push the new element into the array and save the updated array into localStorage using _setItem()_.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete details of the localStorage from here:
https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/html5-local-storage

which helps you achieve your goal.

In short overview, just use the following code to set the array:

```
localStorage.setItem("list_data_key",  JSON.stringify(ArrayData));
```

To retrieve it, use this:

```
var storedData = localStorage.getItem("list_data_key");
if (storedData) {
    ArrayData = JSON.parse(storedData);
}
```

Comment: How can i push a new object to that array which is already exist in our Local Storage